# Node.js - Socket.io not emiting

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm learning about socket.io and real-time interactions between client and server.
Said that, the project that I'm trying to create for my portofolio is a chat-app.

The problem that I'm facing is that Client (chat.js) is not Emiting.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        Chat App
        <button id="increment" onclick="buttonClicked()">+1</button>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/chat.js"> </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

index.js (server)

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
require("dotenv").config()
const Server = require("socket.io")


const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server)
const port = process.env.PORT
const public_directory = path.join(__dirname, "../public")

app.use(express.static(public_directory))

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log("User Connected")
    socket.on("Button", (number)=>{
        console.log("Message: " + str(number))
    })
})

server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port : ${port} `)
})
```

chat.js

```
const socket = io()


function buttonClicked(){
    console.log("+ 1")
    socket.emit("Button", 1)
}
```

When I'm connected I receive the message **User Connected**, so the connection is well established.

Comment: can you add: `socket.on('connect', () => console.log(socket.id));` and `socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'));` to check that the connection is not being dropped on the client side?

Comment: Well I did that and no response at all,  but I tried to implement aswell the disconnect command in server side, and i'm getting disconnected message

Comment: Do you get any errors in the developer tools console? Connection might be dropping.

Comment: I'm getting no errors in the console developer tools

Comment: are you getting `+ 1` in console? is the event being sent? (in chrome, check network tab and select ws to see the messages)

Comment: Well I'm getting the +1 in console, and about the event in network with only `WS` selected, i'm not getting any.
With `All` selected in network, i'm getting requests that look like this : `97:0{"sid":"ko-5QWzbWVdiWe-IAAKp","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}2:40`
From each request it differs only the `sid`

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with in your `index.js` file.

1. <strike>`const Server = require("socket.io")` is wrong. You need to do `{Server}` because the server class is not the default export.</strike>  - Please use the [official syntax](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#how-to-use) for importing socket.io in the server-side: `const io = require('socket.io')(server);`
2. `str` is not a JavaScript function (it's a Python one). Instead you can do `.toString()`

Here is your fixed `index.js` file:

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
require("dotenv").config()

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server)
const port = process.env.PORT
const public_directory = path.join(__dirname, "../public")
console.log(public_directory)

app.use(express.static(public_directory))

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log("User Connected")
    socket.on("Button", (number)=>{
        console.log("Message: " + number.toString())
    })
})

server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port : ${port} `)
})
```

Comment: (1) no you don't, `const libname = require("libname")` is the correct way to use CJS requires. CJS has no "default exports", only ESM does. Instead of `const { Server }`, just use what [the official docs tell you to use](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#how-to-use).

Comment: My apologies. I have updated my answer to use the official syntax that you have mentioed.

Comment: Note that there's also official docs on how to use it with `express`, mentioned on the same link, [3 paragraphs lower](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#in-conjunction-with-express) =)